# Chrome takes way too long after compiling Angular (7) with node 12 using ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We have quite a large Angular(7) application and every time I write some code and save it, the complication time is very fast BUT it takes forever for Chrome to load the page. I'm talking over a minute...

I tried everything and cannot understand what can be the issue.
I checked the network traffic and there is nothing that holds the page from loading... There is just a blank page until it suddenly paints the screen.
How can I debug what's wrong here?

Please note that I'm only talking about dev env using ng serve

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement some lazy loading

Comment: Everything is loaded via lazy loading...
Other teammates of mine don't suffer as I do. I tried incognito and FF but still the same issue

Comment: check the file size on load  , also see if the load time of page reduce on try `ng serve --aot --prod ` check the difference in file size on JIT (`ng serve`) and using aot (`ng serve --aot`) if you want to still reduce the file  add `--prod` flag.

Comment: perhaps you want to check your friends' global cli version and ng version vs yours? If possible, try downgrading, run the project again, and upgrade again to see if the problem persists in other versions?

Comment: its not recommended to use aot while in development, but can make use of the same in some cases  to reduce the  page load time ( Note : it wont reduce compile time though , may be longer than JIT)

Comment: Using the `--aot` does help but the compile time takes FOREVER...